# How wordpress plugin hooks works?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, actions, customization

I am **new** to wordpress development. I am familiar with **joomla's ins-and-out** working mechanish, now i want to **contribute or say learn wordpress**. I found that every thing in wordpress is done through plugin and its hooks and filters. But before diving into writing some cool stuffs, i want to know **how hooks registered in plugin executes ?** which **design patterns** is implemented in wordpress plugin environment ?

OK, lets take  *example*.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_plg_function' );
function my_plg_function() {
  echo 'I am called';
}
```

In above code, plugin's function is registered in wp_head hook, right ? Now what exactly does **add_action** function does and **when wp_head hook runs**, how my plugins function **called** ? Again I am new to this, i am trying to learn and create cool stuffs in wordpress. Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`do_action` is an event and there are many of them throughout your WordPress instance, in the core or your themes and plugins. (Hypothetical) So even when you put an `add_action` in your plugin file but the theme files are read first by order of execution your `add_action` function will still fire at that event or time of the `do_action` it is hooked to.

This is because even the theme files are held before they are executed by a WordPress Core hook called `after_setup_theme` To know the order of all of these check out the [documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Essentially this means that all code should be inserted at some point in this action hook hierarchy, also you can create your own. So when adding code in a file you should be asking "when" in time is this executing? Have the theme files finished loading by this point? Has WordPress itself loaded yet? There are hooks for those things so be sure to read through that documentation

Comment: Can I ask why this was down voted? As far as I know, to be worthy of such an insult I would have to meet the following criteria: _Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect._ From my mobile device I did more research then the OP when asking the question so I don't get it.